# How does one specify a type for variables in Python docstrings for Sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring, autodoc

You can specify types of parameters in Python docstrings like this:

```
def __init__(self, canvas, segments):
    """Class constructor.

    :param canvas: the PDF canvas object
    :param segment: The layer segments to be drawn.

    :type canvas: `canvas.Canvas`
    :type segments: list of str
    """
    ...
```

With Sphinx' autodoc feature, this yields the parameters list, and each parameter is properly tagged with their types.

But how do I do this with instance attributes?  Something like this

```
class Path(object):
    """
    :ivar edge_indices: The indices within `textured_points` of the places.

    :type edge_indices: list of int
    """
```

does not work.  One can put a *single-word* type after the `:ivar` but here, it consists of three words, so that would not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had this same issue.  The answer is `vartype`:

```
class Foo:
    """
    :ivar edge_indices: description
    :vartype edge_indices: list of int
    """
```